# How to pass multiple attribute in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

How to pass multiple attribute to a directive.
How to pass  value 12 of click-to-edit1  inside below div like

```
<div click-to-edit="location.state" click-to-edit1=12></div>
```

and should be accessible in directive controller.please help me out.

**Code:**

App HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl">
    <h2>Editors</h2>
    <div class="field">
        <strong>State:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.state"></div>
    </div>

       <h2>Values</h2>
    <p><strong>State:</strong> {{location.state}}</p>

</div>
```

App directive:

```
app = angular.module("formDemo", []);

app.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
        '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '{{value}} ' +
            '<a ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '<input ng-model="view.editableValue">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>' +
            ' or ' +
            '<a ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: editorTemplate,
        scope: {
            value: "=clickToEdit",
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.view = {
                editableValue: $scope.value,
                editorEnabled: false
            };

            $scope.enableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
            };

            $scope.disableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
                $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
                $scope.disableEditor();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

App controller:

```
app.controller("LocationFormCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.location = {
        state: "California",

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new property inside directives scope:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.location = {
    state: "California",    
  };
});    

app.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
  var editorTemplate = '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
    '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled">' +
    ' {{value}} ' +
    '<a ng-click="enableEditor()">Edit</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div>{{value1}}</div>' +
    '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
    '<input ng-model="view.editableValue">' +
    '<a href="#" ng-click="save()">Save</a>' +
    ' or ' +
    '<a ng-click="disableEditor()">cancel</a>.' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    template: editorTemplate,
    scope: {
      value: "=clickToEdit",
      value1: "=clickToEdit1"
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.view = {
        editableValue: $scope.value,
        editorEnabled: false
      };

      $scope.enableEditor = function() {
        $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
        $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
      };

      $scope.disableEditor = function() {
        $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
      };

      $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
        $scope.disableEditor();
      };
    }
  };
});
```

html:

```
<div class="field">
    <strong>State:</strong>
    <div click-to-edit="location.state" click-to-edit1="12"></div>
</div>
```

working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/e7oTtZNvLdu6w5dgFtfe?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you first tell the div that you want your directive on it.

```
<div click-to-edit value='location.state' value1='12'></div>

app.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
return {
  restrict: "A",
  scope : {
    value : "=",
    value1 : "="
  },
  link : function($scope) {
    console.log("the first value, should be location.state value on the controller", $scope.value);
    console.log("the second value, should be '12'", $scope.value);

  }
}
```

it might seem more logic when you use the directive as a element.

but bottom line is that the diretive looks for attributes on the element, which you then can attach to the directive via the scope. '=' for two way binding, '@' for one way.